Is there a way to know if a file was copied?
I'm using Ubuntu 22.04, and I'm making a bash program (script) to run scripts at startup, shutdown and/or reboot. These things are sensitive and, if poorly done, it could be dangerous for the user/pc, so I'm making multiple checks like, flags/arguments properly parsed, valid arguments, valid files, etc.
When everything is checked I have the following line:
cp -iv $source_file /etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name

I'm using the -i flag to avoid overwriting scripts if it's not what the user wanted, but I don't know how (if there's a way) to know whether the user prompted yes or no, because if the user said no, the script should stop.
Is there a way to do this or should I make a workaround?

https://askubuntu.com/a/554238/380067 ? And then either cp or do nothing?

@kos Yep, as a workaround I was thinking something like that. Detecting if the destination file exists, asking for permission, etc. But those are 5~  lines that could be shrunk to 1 if I could do something like if $boolean_capturing_cp_result; then exit ; fi

There's no boolean in bash, the idiom is to consider anything other than 0 as an error; Raffa is providing you with what you technically want, but beware going that route as you're enforcing a "boolean" layer by casting to "false" only a single case (status code 1); what you really should want to do there is to deal both with user's refusal and with whatever other error may occurr while running cp.

By comparing files' contents
If a file is successfully newly copied to a different filename, the the contents of both files should be identical ... and given that those script files are unlikely to instantly or immediately change contents after the copy process, then ...
You can use cmp right after the copying process to compare the source (original) file to the destination (copied) file with something like this:
#!/bin/bash

cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"

if cmp -s "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"; then
  # Both files are identical
  # Do things based on that here:

else
  # The files are different
  exit 1
fi

or in a simpler one-liner like:
cmp -s orig_file dest_file && echo "files are identical"

and:
cmp -s orig_file dest_file || echo "files are different"

By cp's exit status
cp -i (on newer versions) i.e.
$ cp --version
cp (GNU coreutils) 9.4
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjörn Granlund, David MacKenzie, and Jim Meyering.

(and newer) should return a non success error code of 1 on inputting no by the user (and also on other errors like No such file or directory so keep this in mind) ... Therefore, you could listen for that in your script with e.g. trap and define a function to act upon it like this:
#!/bin/bash

check_status () 
{ 
    local status=$?
    (( status == 1 )) && exit $status
}

trap check_status ERR

# Your "cp -i ..." command below

# Unset the signal trap so the rest of the script gets excluded from that trap
trap - ERR

... and that should terminate (exit) your script if the user input no for cp -i confirmation.
Notice while the above could be a first choice for total control/reporting on multiple files cp -i operations as it can be extended so that, for example, you know which ones were accepted by the user an which ones were ignored like for example:
$ cat copy.sh
#!/bin/bash

check_status () 
{ 
    local status=$?
    (( status == 1 )) && notcopied+=( "$f" )
}

trap check_status ERR

for f in file*; do
  cp -iv "$f" dir/
  done
  
if (( ${#notcopied[@]} > 0 )); then
  printf '%s\n' "The user answered NO to these files:"
  printf '%s\n' "${notcopied[@]}"
  exit 0
fi
$
$ ls file*
file  file1  file.log
$ ls dir/
file  file1  file.log
$
$ ./copy.sh
cp: overwrite 'dir/file'? n
cp: overwrite 'dir/file1'? n
cp: overwrite 'dir/file.log'? y
'file.log' -> 'dir/file.log'
The user answered NO to these files:
file
file1

However, it might be an overkill for single files copying operations as you can directly evaluate the exit status right after the cp -i command like for example:
#!/bin/bash

cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name" || exit 1

... to exit with status 1 on any exit status for cp -i other than 0.
or for example:
#!/bin/bash

cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"
(( $? == 1 )) && exit 1

... to exit with status 1 on error and only if the exit status was 1 for cp -i.
or:
#!/bin/bash

cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"
if (( $? == 0 )); then
  # The user answered "yes" and the copy was successful
  # Do stuff here:
  
else
  # The user probably answered "No" and/or the copy failed
  # exit here:
  exit 0
fi

... to do things on cp -i success and exit otherwise.
Other simpler straightforward ways to just exit the script on any error are:
#!/bin/bash

.
.
.
# Start exit on error
trap exit ERR

# Your command(s)
cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"

# End exit on error
trap - ERR
.
.
.

or similarly with set -e like:
#!/bin/bash

.
.
.
# Start exit on error
set -e

# Your command(s)
cp -iv "$source_file" "/etc/init.d/custom_script_$file_name"

# End exit on error
set +e
.
.
.

... and of course, you can combine both methods i.e. checking/handling errors/exit status and comparing files' contents.

Could there be other error codes than 1? Would it be safer to check if status != 0, and exit in this case?

@ArturMeinild That is based on my test with the current available versions on Ubuntu ... But, yes it could very well change from 1 to any other none 0 and checking status != 0 (trap ... ERR should not trigger on 0 by the way) or even listening to the error signal itself regardless of status is surely an option, though more general.

For golf / sleekness: you could simplify the body of check_status to just (( $? == 1 )) && exit 1, without saving $? (after all we don't expect to exit anything other than 1 :))

Except on my pretty standard Ubuntu 22.04 system, bash, cp -i response of n does NOT return an error:
$ cp -iv myfoo mybar
cp: overwrite 'mybar'? n
$ echo $?
0

When -i is used on cp, even a read only target will not produce an error! You will be informed "cannot create regular file", and asked to try anyway -- no response produces a non zero exit status.

@ubfan1 Not even with trap check_status ERR as in my first example? Could you test that please? … I did the testing on a test machine that had a more recent version of Ubuntu IIRC it was 23.10 I’ll need to check that again when I get back to that machine later but I’m pretty sure that trap was triggered every time I entered n to cp -i prompt.

With the trap, the "y" to try anyway does produce the error return of 1."n" or invalid response produce 0.

@ubfan1 Thanks! So, as it looks, this might not apply to older versions of cp and in that case, using cmp or alike to compare files is probably the better solution although might be less efficient.

@ubfan1 … and I should mention that in the answer now although I’m on my phone away from any Ubuntu machine but based on your very helpful testing … Thanks again.

@ubfan1 My bad, turned out that test machine was running the latest development version of Ubuntu 24.04 ... The good news, however, that Ubuntu 24.04 is due to be released in a couple days ... So, that could be called a discovery by mistake ... My thanks to you again :-) ... I edited the answer accordingly.
